# Interval between 2 scripts

Tags: javascript, timeout, intervals

```js
javascript:var settings = Array(0, 0, 'A', 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 'A', 0, 0, 1, 'none', 'none', 'attack');
$.getScript(
    'https://media.innogamescdn.com/com_DS_DE/scripts/qb_main/scriptgenerator.js');
   setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        (frames.main||self).document.forms[0].submit.click();
    },1000);
```

I have this now. It's not working as I want. If I click this it still only performs the first script. But if I click it the second time I feel the 1000 MS delay... I want this to happen in only 1 click.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) might work.

```js
var settings = ...
setTimeout(function() {
  void(0);document.getElementById...
}, YOUR_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the 2nd half of the script to run *after* the remote script has been loaded, then you can use the second parameter of [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to define a callback to run once the script is loaded:

```
var settings = Array(0, 0, 'A', 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 'A', 0, 0, 1, 'none', 'none', 'attack');

$.getScript(
    'https://media.innogamescdn.com/com_DS_DE/scripts/qb_main/scriptgenerator.js',
    function () {
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_train").click();
        (frames.main||self).document.forms[0].submit.click();
    }
);
```

Comment: @koalawesley You're going to have to be more specific than that. Doesn't work in what way? Syntax error? Not enough of a wait?

Comment: it still only executes the first script. The first script clicks on a button and then it needs to wait a sec and then it needs to execute the second script becuase it changes from pages